# Windows Reserved Partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I'm trying to install a Windows 10 update, but I can't because the size of my partition is 16MB.

I've tried with third-party tools to extend or resize the reserved partition, but the option of doing so is not available:

[image: partitions image]

Why can't my system change the reserved partition?  And what can I do about it?

Comment: You can't extend the 16MB because there isn't free space after it.  What I suggest is merging the unallocated space into that partition.  I would create an image of that partition on another system, delete the partition, create a single partition then apply the image to the new partition.  I hoep you know, that the second disk, isn't bootable by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of unallocated space *in front* of the partition. Because it's very small now, you can easily move it with little risk. Simply move the partition to the front of the disk and extend it to cover all space in front of the Windows partition.

This should be no problem when using [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). You should be able to perform both actions in one step, using the Move/Resize dialog.

I recommend not deleting the partition, because its UUID will change if you recreate it. It may or may not be relevant.

Comment: I'm going to try it today.

Comment: I tried but did not work. The resize option was not available on that partition. Maybe tomorrow I will post images of it (with info of the partition). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution in this case would be to simply create a brand new partition with more space and install W10 there. You could also delete that 16mb extra partition.

Comment: Thanks Obed but... if that's the easy way...

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is not the way out. That will make the person lose all their data in their programs.